# Issue with Rails Controller and Show Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having problem with my show page, it shows my category page well, but when I click my category id, it gives following error:

[image]

This is my Show html page code :

```
<div id="page-index">
  <% @games.each_slice(4) do |game| %>
    <div class="row">
      <% game.each do |game| %>
       <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <%= image_tag(game.coverpath)if game.coverpath.presence%>
              <h4><b>Uncharted</b></h4>
              <p><%= game.description%></p>
              <%= link_to 'Read More', game_path(game), class:'btn btn-primary'%>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

And this is my Category controller code:

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @categories=Category.all
  end
  def new
    @category=Category.new
  end
  def create
    @category=Category.new(category_params)
    if @category.save
      flash[:notice] = 'category created'
      redirect_to categories_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
  def edit
    @category=Category.find(params[:id])
  end
  def update
    @category=Category.find(params[:id])
    @category.update(category_params)
    flash[:notice] = 'category updated'
    redirect_to categories_path
  end
  def destroy
    @category=Category.find(params[:id])
    @category.destroy
    flash[:notice] = 'game deleted'
    redirect_to categories_path
  end
  def show
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    @categories = Category.all
    @games = @categories.games
  end
  private
  def category_params
    params.require(:category).permit(:genre)
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you set retaliation correctly? category has_many games, game belongs_to category?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you Category Model has a relation to games, not your category collection

you could do it with

```
def show
  @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  @categories = Category.all
  @games = @categories.map(&:games) 
end
```

to get all games from each category or doing the following

```
@games = Game.where(category_id: @categories.pluck(:id))
```

or if you want the games from the displayed category

```
@games = @category.games
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@categories = Category.all
```

Here `@categories` is a ActiveRecord_Relation object (try `@categories.class` in rails console) 
If a `has_many` relation is defined between Category and Game like 
in app/models/category.rb

```
has_many :games
```

It means a category object can have many Game objects associated with it.
Since @categories in not a Category object(its a collection of objects defined by the ARel) its throwing an error. Fire up the rails console and try it.

To get games for a category you may first get a category object by

`category = Category.find(<some_id>)`

`games = category.games` (if its a `has_many` relation)

P.S the error simply says that the method games in not defined on the object you are calling it on. You can also try `@categories.methods` to check what methods are defined on that object.